# Can't resolve: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection

Tags: android

**[SOLVED] (Just simply went through entire code, did minor changes and works fine now.)**

.

I'm having constant problems with this error:

`W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection`

I've done a simple math game where I've set 3 different difficulty stages. The math game works such as you get an equation as follows: `3 * 7 = __`, and the player then fills in the empty field and presses `[CORRECT]-button` which will tell the player if it's correct or wrong. Points will be added to the score eaach time the person is right. From the beginning I only had a EASY-difficulty stage coded and have since added codes to the MEDIUM-difficulty stage as well (containing same layout and coding but with harder equations). When I enter the EASY-difficulty stage and solve one equation, I get suddenly thrown out from the EasyActivity to the PlayActivity.

I had (and still have) this problem before creating the MEDIUM-stage as well.  For isntants if I tried using `if`-statement in the PlayActivity's onCreate or onClick, it would behave the same when I entered Easy-stage and tried solving an equation. Any ideas why this is the case?

How my App structure looks like:

```
(a) MainActivity --> here I have a start button which leads to the Menu
   (b) MenuActivity --> is my Menu, where following buttons are found:
      (b.1) Play --> leads to the game (PlayActivity), with following buttons:
             - EasyActivity = easy difficulty (upon press leads to the game)
             - MediumActivity = medium difficulty (upon press leads to the game)
             - HardActivity = hard difficulty stage (not coded yet)
      (b.2) High Score --> leads to the High Score (HighScoreActiviy)
      (b.3) Help --> leads to the game information (HelpActivity)
```

Comment: Can you post full error code?

Comment: Hey Kuvalya. Problem is solved now, I think the changes I made in my code in combination with Shared preferences fixed the problem. Dunno which one exacly, but it works perfectly now.